# ByteToStringConverter does not implement interface member ...IValueConverter.ConvertBack(...)'?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, ivalueconverter

My ByteToStringConverter, it does the job converting Bytes to human readable size (MB, GB, etc)

Error   1   The name "ByteToStringConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:zemanFileManager.Konverteri".   C:\Users\Nikola\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\zemanFileManager\zemanFileManager\zemanFileManager.xaml   14  9   zemanFileManager

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace zemanFileManager.Konverteri
{
    public class ByteToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            string size = "0 KB";

            if (value != null)
            {

                double byteCount = 0;

                byteCount = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

                if (byteCount >= 1073741824)
                    size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824) + " GB";
                else if (byteCount >= 1048576)
                    size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1048576) + " MB";
                else if (byteCount >= 1024)
                    size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1024) + " KB";
                else if (byteCount > 0 && byteCount < 1024)
                    size = "1 KB";    //Bytes are unimportant ;)            
            }

            return size;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

xaml code, in here I also get that ByteToStringConverter does not exist in the namespace although it does exist. I am using another converter called HeaderToImageConverter and that one works just fine...

```
Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="zemanFileManager.ZemanFileManager"

xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
WindowState="Maximized"
Title="ZemanFileManager" Height="700" Width="870" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="870" Icon="Slike/floppySlika.png"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:zemanFileManager"            
              >

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ByteToStringConverter x:Key="BytesToString" />
</Window.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="220" Header="Ime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Vrijeme kreiranja" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CreationTime}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Veličina" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Length, Converter={StaticResource BytesToString}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Ekstenzija"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding  Extension}" />

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML namespace declaration `local` references the namespace `zemanFileManager`, but the converter is in namespace `zemanFileManager.Konverteri`.

Add another namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:zemanFileManager.Konverteri"
...
<converter:ByteToStringConverter x:Key="BytesToString" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately I still get an error ->

[link to error pic](http://i.imgur.com/yAaOrME.jpg)

Comment: Please add a description of that error to your question.